# Assign Dynamic templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to use KnockoutJS to develop a wizard for my asp.net app.

This is my first attempt at using KO.

What I am trying to achieve is assign dynamic templates based on a Click event of an anchor tag.

My HTML looks like this

```
<script id="ParamHomeTmpl" type="text/html">
   <section class="alert alert-info">
       <div class="panel-heading h3  blackincolor"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle redincolor" style="margin-right: 5px"></i>Please Select Parameter Type</div>

       <ul class="blackincolor list-group">
           <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-bind="click: templateToUse" href="#" id="InputType"><b>Input Type:</b> Gives an Option to Select your Key-Value Pairs.</a></li>

           <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-bind="click: templateToUse" href="#" id="ListType"><b>List Type:</b> You can type in a Key and insert a list of values and select one of the values that you created.</a></li>
       </ul>
   </section>
</script>
<script id="InputTypeTmpl" type="text/html">
   <div>
       <p>Input Type</p>
   </div>
</script>
<script id="ListTypeTmpl" type="text/html">
   <div>
       <p>ListType</p>
   </div>
</script>
<script id="BlankTmpl" type="text/html">
   <div>
       <p>Blank</p>
   </div>
</script>
<div class="tab-pane" id="SelectParamType" data-bind="template: { name: templateToUse }">
</div>
```

And finally the actual JS is:

```
var viewModel = {
       currTemplate: function () {
        return "paramHome";
    },
    paramType: ko.observable("Metadata")
};

viewModel.secondStep = function (data, event) {

    // return (event.target.id);
    console.log(data);
};

viewModel.templateToUse = function (data, event) {
    try {
        alert(event.target.id);
        switch (event.target.id) {
            case "InputType":
                return "InputTypeTmpl";

            case "ListType":
                return "ListTypeTmpl";

            default:
                return "BlankTmpl";
        }
    }
    catch (err) { return "ParamHomeTmpl" ;}
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The issue is that when I click the anchor tag from the first step "Select Param Type", the template is not swapped automatically based on the click event target.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/c8tm1193/

Comment: You're down the rabbit hole quite a ways already. I'd suggest taking a few steps back, and looking at implementing a custom binding handler for that plugin (that in itself may present as a challenge), and get help getting that to work first. Currently your question is really rather broad.

Comment: The twitter Bootstrap is just a wrapper to show progress. I only wanted to understand as to how to swap templates for a DIV based on the target ID of an "a href" tag and apply changes. Even if I remove the bootstrap control, I should still be able to work it out. Let me know if this still needs a custom binding.

Comment: I don't quite follow I'm afraid. There's *a lot* of code in your question, but in your comment you ask a different, smaller question. I'd suggest re-asking your actual question (the one you allude to in your comment), with a *small-as-possible* repro.

Comment: I thought by giving out the whole code, this might help someone else who might be trying to do something similar. I didnt realize that this might confuse people. My bad. Shortened the OP now and also included a fiddle. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I came across my previous answer and felt it needed to be fixed.

The main problem with your code is that you're using the function you've bound to the `click` as the template name. You should have a separate observable for the template name, and the function should set its value:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="SelectParamType" data-bind="template: currTemplate">
```

...

```
var viewModel = {
  currTemplate: ko.observable('ParamHomeTmpl'),
  paramType: ko.observable("Metadata")
};
```

Also, you have no `break`s in your switch, so it always falls through to `default`, though you fixed this in your answer.

A secondary problem is that clicking on the bold text in the link causes `event.target` to be the `<b>` element rather than the `<a>`, so you have no `id`. You can avoid this problem by `bind`ing the template name to the function call:

```
data-bind="click: templateToUse.bind($root, 'InputTypeTmpl')"
```

and using the `data` parameter in the function, which then becomes very simple:

```
viewModel.templateToUse = function(data) {
  viewModel.currTemplate(data);
};
```

In fact, you can do away with the function entirely and bind directly to the template name observable:

```
data-bind="click: currTemplate.bind($root, 'InputTypeTmpl')"
```

```js
var viewModel = {
  currTemplate: ko.observable('ParamHomeTmpl'),
  paramType: ko.observable("Metadata")
};

viewModel.secondStep = function(data, event) {

  // return (event.target.id);
  console.log(data);
};

viewModel.templateToUse = function(data) {
  viewModel.currTemplate(data);
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script id="ParamHomeTmpl" type="text/html">
  <section class="alert alert-info">
    <div class="panel-heading h3  blackincolor"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle redincolor" style="margin-right: 5px"></i>Please Select Parameter Type</div>

    <ul class="blackincolor list-group">
      <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-bind="click: currTemplate.bind($root, 'InputTypeTmpl')" href="#" id="InputType"><b>Input Type:</b> Gives an Option to Select your Key-Value Pairs.</a>
      </li>

      <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-bind="click: currTemplate.bind($root, 'ListTypeTmpl')" href="#" id="ListType"><b>List Type:</b> You can type in a Key and insert a list of values and select one of the values that you created.</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</script>
<script id="InputTypeTmpl" type="text/html">
  <div>
    <p>Input Type</p>
  </div>
</script>
<script id="ListTypeTmpl" type="text/html">
  <div>
    <p>ListType</p>
  </div>
</script>
<script id="BlankTmpl" type="text/html">
  <div>
    <p>Blank</p>
  </div>
</script>
<div class="tab-pane" id="SelectParamType" data-bind="template: currTemplate">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach -- using templates -- is wrong. Dynamic HTML is what the `if` binding is for. The only legitimate use for templates (imo) is recursive HTML structure.

***Update*** I no longer subscribe to this view. Templates are useful for recursive HTML *and* when a section of code may take several forms. Bind to a variable and update the variable with the proper template name. Original answer continues below.

I've made the click bindings set an observable that controls which section is displayed.

```js
var viewModel = {
  section: ko.observable('blank'),
  paramType: ko.observable("Metadata")
};

viewModel.secondStep = function(data, event) {

  // return (event.target.id);
  console.log(data);
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<section class="alert alert-info">
  <div class="panel-heading h3  blackincolor"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle redincolor" style="margin-right: 5px"></i>Please Select Parameter Type</div>

  <ul class="blackincolor list-group">
    <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-bind="click: section.bind(0, 'input')" href="#" id="InputType"><b>Input Type:</b> Gives an Option to Select your Key-Value Pairs.</a>
    </li>

   <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-bind="click: section.bind(0, 'list')" href="#" id="ListType"><b>List Type:</b> You can type in a Key and insert a list of values and select one of the values that you created.</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<div data-bind="if:section()=='input'">
  <p>Input Type</p>
</div>
<div data-bind="if:section()=='list'">
  <p>ListType</p>
</div>
<div data-bind="if:section()=='blank'">
  <p>Blank</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roy. This works in the current context of the question. But, I am using "Bootstrap Wizard" to show the progress flow. If I do not use `applyBindingsToNode`, I will be forced to write a custom binding handler for the Bootstrap Wizard control.

Comment: Let me caution you that avoiding custom binding handlers is not a good long-term strategy. They're not that difficult, and they tend to make code simpler and more elegant.

Comment: I do intend to learn writing Custom binding handlers in the long term. I have started picking up Knockout only recently(its only been 2 days now) and my first priority was to understand the fundamentals thoroughly before proceeding to advanced concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed using

`applyBindingsToNode`

Code:

```
viewModel.templateToUse = function(data, event) {
    try {

        switch (event.target.id) {

            case "InputType":
                templateType = "InputTypeTmpl";
                break;

            case "ListType":
                templateType = "ListTypeTmpl";
                break;

            case "FileType":
                templateType = "FileTypeTmpl";
                break;

            case "DataBaseType":
                templateType = "DataBaseTypeTmpl";
                break;

            default:
                return "BlankTmpl";

        }
    } catch (err) {
        return "BlankTmpl";
    }
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById("Attributes"), {
        template: {
            name: templateType
        }
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/c8tm1193/1