# Using ForEach to bind data to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am just starting to use Knockout so please dont mind my ignorance.

I am trying to use knockout to build a SPA which basically swaps templates and does some data binding to show a list of array (there are many more functions but I will be sticking to the scope of the question here)

When I do a data-bind using a ViewModel property, I get an error saying that property is not defined when I click on the first link "Input Type", which should populate the table with the ParamData. In my case I am facing the below error

> "ParamData is not defined"

I have created a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/c8tm1193/3/

The HTML looks like this:

```
<script id="ParamHomeTmpl" type="text/html">
   <section class="alert alert-info">
       <div class="panel-heading h3  blackincolor"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle redincolor" style="margin-right: 5px"></i>Please Select Parameter Type</div>

       <ul class="blackincolor list-group">
           <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-bind="click: templateToUse" href="#" id="InputType"><b>Input Type:</b> Gives an Option to Select your Key-Value Pairs.</a></li>

           <li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-bind="click: templateToUse" href="#" id="ListType"><b>List Type:</b> You can type in a Key and insert a list of values and select one of the values that you created.</a></li>
       </ul>
   </section>
</script>
<script id="InputTypeTmpl" type="text/html">
   <div>
       <p>Input Type</p>
   </div>
   <table id="paramtypeTbl" data-bind="template:{ name: 'paramDataTmpl'}">
   </table>
</script>
<script id="ListTypeTmpl" type="text/html">
   <div>
       <p>ListType</p>
   </div>
</script>
<script id="paramDataTmpl" type="text/html">
   <div data-bind="foreach: ParamData">

       <span></span><span>Products</span>
       <table>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Key</th>
                   <th>Value</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td data-bind="text: paramKey"></td>
                   <td data-bind="text: paramValue"></td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
</script>
<script id="BlankTmpl" type="text/html"></script>
<div class="tab-pane" id="SelectParamType" data-bind="template: { name: 'ParamHomeTmpl' }"></div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="Attributes" data-bind="template: { name: templateToUse }"></div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var templateType = "BlankTmpl";

var Tempdata = ([{
    paramKey: "Sourabh",
    paramValue: "Tewari"
}]);

var viewModel = {
    ParamData: ko.observableArray(Tempdata)
};

viewModel.templateToUse = function (data, event) {
    try {

        switch (event.target.id) {

            case "InputType":
                templateType = "InputTypeTmpl";
                break;

            case "ListType":
                templateType = "ListTypeTmpl";
                break;

            case "FileType":
                templateType = "FileTypeTmpl";
                break;

            case "DataBaseType":
                templateType = "DataBaseTypeTmpl";
                break;

            default:
                return "BlankTmpl";

        }
    } catch (err) {
        return "BlankTmpl";
    }
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById("Attributes"), {
        template: {
            name: templateType
        }
    });

};

viewModel.ParamView = function (data, event) {
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById("paramtypeTbl"), {
        ParamData: ko.observableArray(Tempdata),
        template: {
            name: ParamView
        }
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: This is the same query as you asked y'day? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499059/assign-dynamic-templates  ... I was hoping to give you some pointers, but haven't managed to find time yet, but meanwhile you shouldn't have the same question twice. Ideally you should close this one and continue to improve your original one.

Comment: nope, this is not the same question. I figured out the answer to my last question. I am drafting the answer to that and would post it in a moment.In this one, I am facing a problem with binding the `ParamData` and show it in a table.

Comment: ...or am I wrong - is this a different question about the same code - have you now solved your orig question and moved on to a new problem? If so then you should answer your orig Q yourself, so people (like me!) know you no longer need help.

Comment: ah ok great, in which case please excuse my orig comment.

Comment: For my previous question, I am giving an answer as I write. Its ok mate. Thanks for looking into my question.

Comment: Depending on which sub-item in the anchor you click, the target may not have an id.

Comment: erm...could you suggest me a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your viewmodel for the template should be passed as the third argument to `applyBindingsToNode`. Also, since your anchor has sub-parts, the target of the click event might not be what you expect. Better to pass the desired template name explicitly.

HTML:

```
<li><a class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" data-bind="click: templateToUse.bind(0,'InputTypeTmpl')" href="#" id="InputType"><b>Input Type:</b> Gives an Option to Select your Key-Value Pairs.</a></li>
```

JS:

```
viewModel.templateToUse = function (name) {
    if (typeof name === 'string') templateType = name;
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById("Attributes"), {
        template: {
            name: templateType
        }
    }, {
        ParamData: ko.observableArray(Tempdata)
    });
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c8tm1193/5/